# Can't add UILabel to UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to add a UILabel to a custom UICollectionViewCell. On my UICollectionViewCell I've created a method which will instantiate and add the UILabel to it:

```
class VideoCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    func showOptions() {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 25))
        label.text = "test"
        contentView.addSubview(label)
    }

}
```

So, when the cell is tapped, I'm going to call this method:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? VideoCell else {
        fatalError("Wrong instance for dequeued cell")
    }
    cell.showOptions()
}
```

Although no error occurs, the label does not appear in the cell.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is here

```
guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? VideoCell else {
    fatalError("Wrong instance for dequeued cell")
}
```

you must use cellForItemAtIndexPath to return that cell not by dequeuing

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating the answer of @Sh_Khan the code should look as following :-

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? VideoCell
    return cell ?? UICollectionViewCell()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? VideoCell else {
        fatalError("Wrong instance for dequeued cell")
    }
    cell.showOptions()
}
```